# Multiple use cases with multiple lifecycles and same camera

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'd like to display preview in `Activity` and also periodicaly do image captures in `LifecycleService` in the background (using `startForeground()`).

So I've created a singleton with `ProcessCameraProvider`.

In `Activity` I do:

```kotlin
processCameraProvider.await().run {
    try {
        unbindAll()
        bindToLifecycle(
            this@MainActivity,
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
            Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.camera.surfaceProvider)
            }
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.w(e)
    }
}
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, Intent(this, CaptureService::class.java))
```

And in the `LifecycleService`, I do:

```kotlin
processCameraProvider.await().bindToLifecycle(
    this@CaptureService,
    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
    imageCapture
)
```

The periodic image capturing in the service works as expected, but as soon as I bind the `LifecycleService`, the preview stops. How can I fix this?

I'm using CameraX version 1.4.0-alpha01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CameraX does not currently support binding multiple use case to same camera with different lifecycle. This is because CameraX using a single lifecycle to manage the camera state. Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#lifecycles)

If you still need to bind multiple use case for the same camera with different lifecycle. You can try to create a custom lifecycle component that manage it camera lifecycle, then bind all of your use case to the custom lifecycle component, and start and stop the custom lifecycle component as needed.

But, that workaround is not good practice, and it may lead to unexpected behavior, if you are not careful.

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a separate **ProcessCameraProvider** instance for the LifecycleService. You can do this by calling the **ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance()** method in the **onCreate()** method of the **LifecycleService**.

```
// In the Activity
processCameraProvider.await().run {
    try {
        unbindAll()
        bindToLifecycle(
            this@MainActivity,
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
            Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.camera.surfaceProvider)
            }
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.w(e)
    }
}
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, Intent(this, CaptureService::class.java))

// In the LifecycleService
val serviceProcessCameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

serviceProcessCameraProvider.await().bindToLifecycle(
    this@CaptureService,
    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
    imageCapture
)
```